# Unique ID with ::InterlockedIncrement (VC++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, increment

Using VC++, to get a unique ID that counts upwards, I was wondering whether this is legal in a multi-threaded application?

```
uint32_t GetNewId() { return ::InterlockedIncrement(&lastId); }
```

Basically, I am wondering whether InterlockedIncrement just protects the increment, or whether the return value is also guarded against race conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is legal - the access which consists of

- read, then
- increment, then
- write, then
- return the incremented value to the caller

will be atomic. Just don't forget that it's 32 bit and can overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Function results are returned in registers and/or stack.  Each thread has a separate stack and register set so, yes, this is safe.  The InterlockedIncrement will do what it does an its returned value is then no different to any other function result - your function can be interruted and reentered from another thread and will return the correct result for both.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: And for some under the hood explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check is to go to the [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> This function is **atomic** with respect to calls to other interlocked
>   functions.